# MFC and Scripting?

Tags: mfc, scripting

I have an MFC application.

What scripting library can I use to give users to access my application via scripting?

Can I do something like:
Use JavaScript + MFC and build a front-end using JavaScript and mini-HTML viewer in a single EXE?

Maybe this question should be:
I like server-side JavaScript and MFC/C++. Can I compile an embedded Javascript and execute it inside my MFC/Javascript shell front-end to present a Win32 app and script whole application logic via JavaScript?

It needs to be closed-source, so I cannot use GPL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CodeProject article [Adding Macro Scripting language support to existing MFC Application](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/mfcscripthost.aspx) sounds promising...